# Well built php applications to learn from?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, authentication

I was wondering if any of you would be able to recommend some of your favorite open source php applications in terms of code quality and proper programming technique.

Though I have been using frameworks for quite a while, I would love to see how professional applications go about this.

I'm particularly interested in

- MVC
- authentication

Thanks a million!

**Edit**: Perhaps I didn't explain too clearly. What I was looking for most are fully functional applications that have their own built-in custom frameworks. I want to see how a professional level app is built and structured when there's no consideration for it's own framework to be used by others.

That being said, it looks like zend is the way to go! Thanks for the suggestions. I will take a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/), which supports MVC, Authentication, and that's just the tip of the iceberg.

**Edit**: Since I apparently misread, you can probably take a look at source code such as

- http://www.manning.com/allen/ZFiA_Code.zip

( From the Manning Zend Framework in Action book )

Another book that provides full source code to a CMS is Pro Zend Techniques:

- http://www.apress.com/book/downloadfile/4469

Here's a whole slew of search results for applications tagged with Zend on github:

- http://github.com/search?q=zend&type=Repositories&x=0&y=0

Comment: Didn't he want applications? He mentioned frameworks in his post and wanted to see "professional applications" built with it...

Answer (score 2):

WordPress may be a good app to the end user, but it would be bad to learn good PHP code from. I agree that the Zend Framework is an excellent place to start. Not only is there code very good, but they have excellent documentation and tutorials. I would start here: http://www.framework.zend.com/manual/en/

Zend Framework provides both MVC and authentication/access control. For auth and access look at Zend_Auth and Zend_Acl.

This is a good guide to getting started with MVC in Zend: http://www.framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart

Some applications that have been built around the Zend Framework include Magento (an ecommerce engine) and Digitalus (a CMS). Both are open source.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Zend Framework.

It is a great example of object oriented code, using MVC.

There's also a whole set of classes related to authentication, implemented in an easy to understand and extensible way: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.html